# JavaScript: Listening for keypress while window is minimized

Tags: javascript, keypress, event-listener

Is there any way to do this? It's not a keylogger, I just want to mess around with analyzing typing speed and technique, etc and I would much rather make a web app or a chrome extension than a native GUI app.

Comment: Javascript events are tied to DOM elements present on the current page. You can't attach an event to anything outside of that.

Answer (score 5):

No. When the window is minimized and doesn't have focus (as would seem to be the case in your scenario), even the browser doesn't receive the keypress (on most operating systems), much less pass it on to your window. Your window, and thus the JavaScript code in it, will only see a keypress when the browser is not minimized and your window/tab has focus.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript events are tied to DOM elements present on the current page. You can't listen to an event on anything outside of that page, let alone that window.